# React Native Multiple BottomSheets with useRef and forwardRef from ContextProvider - (Error: Right operand of 'in' is not an object)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, bottom-sheet

I've created a context provider that loops through an array of BottomSheets (Modals), creates a ref for each sheet, then passes the ref using forwardRef to each Sheet/Modal. I've made the handleShowModal function available via the provider to use in button components.

Is there a better way of doing this? Everything I've tried has failed, with the error:

> Right operand of 'in' is not an object

**Here is my ContextProvider (SheetContextProvider) - Imports are omitted**

```js
const modals = [
    { name: 'wallet', component: WalletModal, snapPoints: '45%' },
    { name: 'shipping', component: ShippingModal, snapPoints: '45%' },
    { name: 'listings', component: ListingsModal, snapPoints: '90%' },
];

export default function SheetContextProvider({ children }) {
    const refs = useRef([]);

    const handleShowModal = useCallback((index) => {
        refs.current[index].present();
    }, []);

    const value = { handleShowModal };

    return (
        <BottomSheetModalProvider>
            <SheetContext.Provider value={value}>
                {children}

                {modals.map((item, index) => {
                    const Modal = item.component;
                    return <Modal ref={(element) => (refs.current[index] = element)} key={index} />;
                })}
            </SheetContext.Provider>
        </BottomSheetModalProvider>
    );
}
```

**Button component that accesses handleShowModal from context provider:**

```js
// Sheet index is referenced from sheets array in SheetContextProvider
const SHEET_INDEX = 1;
const LISTINGS_TEXT = 'Listings';

export default function ListingsAction() {
    const { handleShowModal } = useSheetContext();

    return (
        <Pressable onPress={() => handleShowModal(SHEET_INDEX)} style={styles.action}>
            <MaterialIcons name="storefront" size={22} color="white" style={styles.icon} />
            <Text style={styles.text}>{LISTINGS_TEXT}</Text>
        </Pressable>
    );
}
```

**Here is the BottomSheet Modal that is suppose to open when the button is pressed:**

```js
const ListingsModal = forwardRef(function ({}, ref) {
    const snapPoints = '45%';
    const listingsRef = useRef(null);

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
        return {
            present() {
                listingsRef.current.present();
            },
        };
    });

    return (
        <BottomSheetModal
            ref={listingsRef}
            index={0}
            snapPoints={snapPoints}
            style={styles.container}
            backgroundStyle={styles.background}
            handleIndicatorStyle={styles.handle}
        >
            <View>
                <Text>Listings Sheet</Text>
            </View>
        </BottomSheetModal>
    );
});

export default ListingsModal;
```